# Get all images in uploads directory and list them

Tags: uploads

I'm trying to get all of the images inside a specific sub-directory within the WordPress uploads directory, and then output all of those images.

```
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir(); 

$logo_dir = ( $upload_dir['baseurl'] . '/logos/' );
echo $logo_dir . '-----<br />';
$images = glob( $logo_dir . "*.PNG" );
foreach( $images as $image ) {
    echo $image;
}
```

`$logo_dir` is outputting the correct directory. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with the foreach.

Comment: Are all of your images png files that have an uppercase `.PNG` extension?

Comment: @Milo Yes they are

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$upload_dir['baseurl']` should be `$upload_dir['basedir']`. You want the server path, not the URL of the directory.